# where to find the Subdomain and Tenant's Endpoints for API REST Call

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to know how to get the URL for the API rest call,and also the ACCESS_TOKEN in salesforce marketing cloud

Comment: remember to mark the answers received, as being accepted. This will benefit the community when searching for relevant solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new installed package with a [server-to-server api component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-s2s-client-credentials.htm).

This is how you do it:

1. Go to **Marketing Cloud | Administration | Installed Packages**.
2. Click **New**.
3. Give the package a name and description.
4. Select to create the package with enhanced functionality.
5. **Save** the package.
6. Under Components, click **Add Component**.
7. Select **API Integration**. After you add an API integration component, it can’t be removed.
8. Select **Server-to-server** integration type.
9. Set the properties for the integration, including scopes - depending on the purpose of your integration.
10. **Save** the component.

Now you have tenant specific endpoints and your Client ID and Secret. You can now use the [new v2 token endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm) to get your access token.